# How do you get rid of <SKMetalLayer: 0x155851c90>: calling -display has no effect. printing in the log?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, sprite-kit, ios9

I have a SpriteKit game and whenever I run this on a device : calling -display has no effect. This makes all of the nodes zPositions messed up which is really annoying to fix. So I was wondering if there is any way to fix it or if I just have to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting PrefersOpenGL=YES in Info.plist to enable OpenGL mode in SpriteKit? For certain things like custom shader performance, the new Metal mode for SpriteKit is half baked and not working properly.

Comment: just tried setting this but still happening on device running iOS 9.3.5. The error msg in question seems to appear every time the device is rotated between portrait & landscape

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same message, seems to be a bug. I haven't seen any adverse effects on my games. Are you sure you actually gave your sprites a zPosition? You cannot rely on SpriteKit doing it by itself because by default

```
 skView.ignoresSiblingOrder
```

is set to true to improve performance. This means SpriteKit might ignore the order of how you are adding the sprites to the scene, hence you get different zPositions than you might expect.

Giving all your sprites a zPosition should solve your problem.

Comment: I have set the zPositions. With iOS 8 everything was right but iOS 9 screwed everything up